# VB.NET aspx page use codebehind variable in If statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use codebehind variable in if statement. This is my statement.

```
<title><%If ("<%= title_tag%>".ToString().Contains("MI") = True) Then%>
        MI
   <% Else %>
        MC
    <%End If %>
</title>
```

But If I remove the codebehind variable and just use

```
<title><%If ("Home Care MI".ToString().Contains("MI") = True) Then%>
        MI
   <% Else %>
        MC
    <%End If %>
</title>
```

It works well. I've also tried escaping codebehind variable in two curly braces but it didn't help.

Comment: what is title_tag ? if it is any control like label, then put  <%= title_tag.ToString()

Comment: It is a variable, BTW it's solved for now. See the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came through. Thanks for your support. I think the issue was in contains and tostring function.

```
<title><%IF title_tag = "Earlier Title" Then%>
            MI      
        <% Else %>
        MC
        <%End If %>
        </title>
```

Comment: Actually that wasn't a problem, it actually worked with `toString()` and `contains` too

Comment: could have, But surprisingly when I removed them it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declare the variable as `public` in your code behind file and no need to use `<%` or `"` around variales...

```
<title><%If (title_tag.ToString().Contains("MI") = True) Then%>
        MI
   <% Else %>
        MC
    <%End If %>
</title>
```

Comment: Didn't help :( still showing 500 error. I'm able to access it on the page as <%=title_tag%> but not in if statement.

Comment: I replicated this and it works!, where have you declared your variable ? What is the variable type? Show the code behind where you have declared it

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a ternary operator for your conditions, and you only need to surround the contents of the title tag with <%= %> once.

**C#**

```
<title>
    <%= title_tag.ToString().Contains("MI") ? "MI" : "MC"%>
</title>
```

**VB.NET**

```
<title>
    <%= IIf(title_tag.ToString().Contains("MI"), "MI", "MC")%>
</title>
```

**To do this through the Code Behind page:**

You would just need to give the title tag an ID and runat="server", e.g.

```
<title id="titleCtrl" runat="server"></title>
```

Then on the code behind after the title_tag variable has been filled, write the iif statement and give titleCtrl.text the result:

```
titleCtrl.Text = IIf(title_tag.ToString().Contains("MI"), "MI", "MC")
```